# how to remove grub from win 11

Tags: boot, 20.04, windows, grub4dos

I have used a Ubuntu installer on USB on my old hard drive, but after it finished, I switched to my main HDD and got the grub-gnu bootloader installed on it (I can boot into Windows using the boot menu). I tried using the chainloader command, but it didn't find any non-existent grub files. Please help me, and thanks.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? What brand/model system? Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/  If you have an ESP on Ubuntu drive, you can edit fstab with that ESP's UUID & reinstall grub.